# Auto resize two images in a div when browser width changes

Tags: css, image, width, scale

I have looked at many different peoples answers to this problem but they only account for one image.
I am having a problem with the the two images that i have placed in my header, when i resize my browser i want them to scale down with it so that they dont displace my whole site.

i have it hosted in dropbox so you can see what my problem is: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13722201/Dorset%20Designs/home.html

also another problem im having is un attaching the footer from the bottom of the screen and putting it below the body so users have to scroll down.
p.s I attached the footer to the bottom many months ago and I forgot how to undo it.

SORRY FOR THE TERRIBLY MESSY CODE

thanks in advance

Arran, 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it. First, style each image using CSS to have `width:100%` and `height:auto`. This makes them respond to the sizes of their containers. Lose those `width` and `height` attributes from the `img` tag - I'm not even sure if those are valid anymore.

Now here's where the clever part comes. Your images are `550px` and `298px` wide, which is roughly a 65%:35% ratio. When the header is at its most narrow point before breaking, it's about as wide as the sum of the two. So give the big image's container `max-width:65%`, and the small image's container `div` `max-width:35%`.

This way, when the browser window is smaller, the images scale down correspondingly - and don't become larger than they need to be when the window is wide. I tried it out on your page, and I think it worked - see if it works for you. :)

Comment: Thank you so much :) that has solved the scaling bit, but now the whole header div goes below the navigation bar. is it something to do with position tag or margins.

Comment: I put my footer in ages ago and I dont know how i can put it below everything so the page scrolls down to see it. at the moment it is attached to the bottom of the browser. Thank you so much for the help